# Mac sees mangled filenames from Linux SAMBA share

Tags: linux, macos, network-shares, samba, smb

Certain filenames in my SAMBA shares from Linux are not getting transmitted properly. It's certain files in certain folders and it doesn't affect all folders or all files within a single folder. I can find no discerning pattern to the mangling but hoping that this is a known problem. No amount of reboot, restart, etc. will fix this problem.

The filenames, when they get mangled, all end up in this form:

```
0JY4B3~H.M4V 
0MBS1O~M.M4V 
0NKDX9~R.M4V 
0O0ZTA~A.M4V
```

These are MPEG4 files. The extension remains intact.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you edit the question and add what those filenames are *supposed* to be?  can you also add your *smb.conf* (at least the name mangling options), or perhaps post it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.ca) and provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

Those are short filenames, created by Samba's name mangling so that SMB clients that lack case sensitivity won't choke on them. See the **NAME MANGLING** section in the `smb.conf(5)` man page for more details. Most likely you have multiple filenames that vary only by case.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I'm quite certain it's not filenames varying only by case, because each filename has an index number prefix that's different. Could it be because of filename length?

Comment: @me2: explicit examples of the actual filenames would be good.  filename length is a possible cause, as are colon characters (":") (or other nonstandard characters) in the filename.